# How to construct a clickable link with a scope using Ransack and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have the requirement to have some scopes as clickable links in my application. This will allow the user to change the data they are seeing as required. Using Ransack and it's ransackable_scopes functionality I am very close. I do need to retain any filtering Ransack has done when the user clicks the scope.

I've got the scopes working but now I just need to construct the clickable link.

Here's my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base    

    scope :upward_trending, -> { where( "status > ?", 100).where(above_revenue_average: true).order('end_date DESC') }
scope :downward_trending, -> { where( "status < ?", 100).order('end_date DESC') }

    def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:upward_trending, :downward_trending]
    end
end
```

Now in my view I've added these two scopes as hidden fields, like so:

```
        <%= search_form_for @q, :html => {:class => 'filter-form'} do |f| %>

        <div>

            <%= f.hidden_field :upward_trending %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :downward_trending %>

            <%= f.label :name_cont, "Search", class: 'label' %>
            <%= f.search_field :name_cont, class: 'form-control input-box', :placeholder => 'Search' %>

        </div>

        <div>

            <%= f.submit "Filter", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <%= link_to "Clear Search", request.path, class:"btn btn-default" %>

        </div>
        <% end %>
```

From here I just need to create the links and it should work.. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by creating hidden fields for each scope and then creating a button with onclick javascript:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :upward_trending %>

<%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary scope-button upward_trending', :id => "upward_trending", :onclick => "document.getElementById('q_downward_trending').value = 0; document.getElementById('q_upward_trending').value = 1;") do %>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-2x"></i><br>Upward<br>Trending
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was planning to do dirty way. (But haven't yet)

- create `search_form_for` every scope (you will have 2 form for your case)
- set hidden field with own criteria (as you do in your code but each in own form)
- make submit button looks like link (with css I think it is not very difficult. You can see [Bootstrap button appeared as link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options))

Not very clean or elegant.

Comment: Hey @twnaing thanks for your answer. I think the challenge with this is it might remove any filtering from the main search_form_for. I ended up going even dirtier, I'll show you in an answer.

Comment: I misread __do need to retain__. Sorry @bnussey and thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problems, hope it helps you.