# Rails filter with button or link_to using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ransack

I am developing a rails application using the Ransack gem and below is the code that I have written so far to filter my database which works like a charm. Now what I am trying to do is to add additional button like filter options to my index view (where each button has pre-defined filter value). In other words, once the database is first filtered with a brand name, then I would like users to be able to further filter the database by clicking one of the buttons which has a pre-defined filter value of say 'colour = white', then rails will show all the data with the selected brand name and the colour of white).

**Controller**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
@q = Project.ransack(params[:q])
@projects = @q.result(distinct: true)
@projects_count = @q.result.count
@projects = Kaminari.paginate_array(@projects).page(params[:page]).per(30)
end
```

**Index View**

```
<%= search_form_for @q, remote: true, :builder => SimpleForm::FormBuilder  do |f| %>
<%= f.input :brand_id_eq, label: false, collection: Brand.all.map{ |f| [f.name, f.id] }, prompt: "All", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
<%= f.button :submit, label: "Search", input_html: { class: "btn btn-primary" } %>
<% end %>
...
<span class="data-sort all"><%= link_to "All",q: {color_cont: 'white'}, :class => 'link-sort', :remote => true, :method => :post %></span>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#projects').html('<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'index') %>').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

The problem that I am facing with this approach using the Ransack gem is that when I click the link_to filter button, it does filter the database with the pre-defined filter value of 'white color' however it resets all the previously selected filter options.

Is my approach correct or any better way to achieve this other than using the link_to option?

**SOLUTION**

I finally got this working using the rail's scope method and a simple jQuery code as shown in my final code below. One thing that I did initially wrong was that I set the name of the scope same as one of my db column name which caused an error. Once I changed the scope name to 'status1', not 'stock_no', it started to work. Hope this helps.

**Defined Scope**

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :status1, -> { where( stock_no = "15251" ) }

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
[:status1]
end
```

**Index.erb**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :status1 %>
<%= f.submit "Stock", :id => "status1", :onclick => "document.getElementById('q_status1').value = 1;", class: 'btn btn-primary status1' %>
```

Comment: Hey jin, what does document.getElementById().value = 1 do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591645/how-to-construct-a-clickable-link-with-a-scope-using-ransack-and-rails). It is somewhat what you are trying to do, except instead of a submit button, just make yours a button for filtering. It needs to be inside your `search_form_for` I'm pretty sure as well. And then write a jquery function to submit when the button is clicked like:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
    $(".data-sort").on('click', function() {
        $("form.your-search-form-classname").trigger('submit.rails');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Try removing the `(boolean = true)` attribute from the scope. I tested with a similar app of my own and it worked well.

**UPDATE 2**

I put the following in my app (where status is a column in by db just like your stock_no) and a got the correct query from my database:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :stock_no %>
<%= f.submit "Stock", :id => "stock_no", :onclick => "document.getElementById('q_stock_no').value = 1;", class: 'btn btn-primary stock_no' %>

scope :stock_no, -> { where( status: 2 ) }

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:stock_no]
end
```

Are you sure you are putting the scope in the right model?

Comment: Hi Chase, thank you!! It seems like the right solution for what I am trying to do. However, as I am new to ROR, I am struggling with defining (whitelisting) the scope of my search. Here is what I have done: (1) scope :color, -> { where(color_id: '2') } then (2)  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil) [:color] end (3) and on my view page,  <%= f.hidden_field :color %> then <span class="data-sort all"><%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary scope-button color', :id => "color", :remote => true %>. I am sure I am not doing this correctly.  Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Add the following to your button_tag: , `:onclick => "document.getElementById('q_color').value = 1;"`. That will make your search results filter using your scope! if you want to add more buttons similar to this one, I would suggest writing some jQuery to set the other buttons values to 0 when one is clicked. The filter is applied when it's value is 1, and ignored when 0. Hope this helps!

Comment: I added the code to my button tag but still not working. I just updated my question and it shows the code that I have tried so far. Anything else I can perhaps try? Thanks.

Comment: When I add this code 'onclick => "document.getElementById('q_color').value = 1;', the parameter of the color returns **1**. I don't think it is linked to the scope properly. When I change the value to '12525' like this ':onclick => "document.getElementById('q_color').value = 12525;"', the parameter of the color returns the value of **12525** and it filters the data. I am very confused here.

Comment: Or is it something to do with the jQuery as you mentioned above?

Comment: It might be the syntax, I could be wrong but I'm not sure that you can use `stock_no = "15251"` try `stock_no: "15251"` or `stock_no: 15251` if `stock_no` is an int in your database.

Comment: I just tried them all but none of them worked. (I think stock_no: "15251" is the right syntax since stock_no is a string, not an int. It returns the value of '1' when it's clicked. I assume it is something to do with my controller or jQuery? It returns the value of 1 and somehow it is supposed to trigger the filter on the database with the stock_no of 15251? I spent the last two days trying to fix this but still no luck.

Comment: I finally realised what I have done wrong. It was the naming of each scope needs to be different from any existing column names in my db. I just changed the scope name to a random name (status1), and it is functioning perfectly well. Thank you so much for your help. I accepted this as an answer.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out! You might want to say what you finally have in your question since there are quite a few comments here, in case others come along with a similar question!

Comment: I put my final code in the question above for others to view. Once again, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`<%= link_to "All",q: {color_cont: 'white'}, :class => 'link-sort', :remote => true, :method => :post %>`

with

`<%= link_to "All",q: {color_cont: 'white', brand_id_eq: params[:q][:brand_id_eq]}, :class => 'link-sort', :remote => true, :method => :post %>`

Here assumption is

> Once the database is **first filtered with a brand name**, then I would like users to be able to **further filter** the database by clicking **one of the buttons** which has a pre-defined filter value

Comment: I get an error of _undefined local variable or method `brand_id_eq'_when I replace the code with the one you suggested above. Also I actually have 5 other filters on my index page other than the brand filter (only mentioned one for the sake of the simplicity of the question). Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The easiest solution is create a hidden variable inside the form for each link filter. When user clicks on the link, related hidden variable should get update using jQuery and then submit the form.

Comment: Thank you Amit. I got this working with the scope. Thanks.