# How to add filter by calculated value to activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I have accounts that can be in block.

```
account.rb
has_many :blocks

block.rb
belongs_to :account
```

Block model has fields `blocked_at` and `unblocked_at`. I need to filter accounts that are (were) in block more then X days. For selecting current status I have field `blocked` in my `account` model.
For displaying how many days account is blocked I add this to AA table:

```
 column 'Days blocked' do |account|
      (Date.today - account.blocks.last.blocked_at.to_date).to_i if account.blocked
 end
```

The question is how to filter it by this field now?

Comment: Did you take a look at this [article by Nikil Gupta](http://nikhgupta.com/code/activeadmin/custom-filters-using-ransacker-in-activeadmin-interfaces/)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just create a custom scope like so:

```
scope :scope_name, -> { where( 'Days blocked' > X ) }
```

(`scope_name` being whatever you name it and `X` being however many days you wish)

You need this so Ransack knows you can use this scope in your controller:

```
def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
   [:scope_name]
end
```

And in your controller:

```
@accounts = @q.result.scope_name
```

Note: This will filter by this scope all the time, if you want to filter only when the user clicks a button or selects the filter, see this question: [Rails filter with button or link_to using Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178311/rails-filter-with-button-or-link-to-using-ransack/45195198?noredirect=1#comment77533643_45195198)

Comment: thanks for your attention, but I need dynamic filter. For example I should be able to find accounts that are blocked for more than 10 days.

Comment: I believe that should work for that, if 'Days blocked' is a column in your AA table that is dynamically updated.