# ROR + Ransack: Filter with button or link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I have referenced these 2 stackoverflow posts, but i can't seem to get `q[categories_name_cont]` to be populated with "CategoryName" in my url: `/articles/browse?utf8=✓&q[categories_name_cont]=&commit=CategoryName` after i click the button named "CategoryName" for example.

1) [Rails filter with button or link_to using Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178311/rails-filter-with-button-or-link-to-using-ransack)
2) [How to construct a clickable link with a scope using Ransack and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591645/how-to-construct-a-clickable-link-with-a-scope-using-ransack-and-rails)

**browse.html.erb**

```
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= search_form_for @q, url: browse_articles_path, method: :get do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :categories_name_cont %>
      <%= f.submit category.name, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick => "document.getElementById('q_categories_name_cont').value = '#{category.name}'" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
  def browse
    @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
    @articles = @q.result.includes(:categories, :users)
    @categories = Category.with_articles.order('name ASC').all
  end
```

**UPDATE:**

1) Hardcoding document.getElementById('q_categories_name_cont').value = "CategoryName" didn't result in this url either.. 
`/articles/browse?utf8=✓&q[categories_name_cont]=CategoryName` after i click the button named "CategoryName"

2) I ended up using the below method to pass parameters to the url:

```
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="/articles/browse?utf8=✓&q[categories_name_cont]=<%= category.name %>">
    </a>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually fill that in.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :categories_name_cont, params[:q].try(:[], :categories_name_cont) %>
```

It can get quite annoying though. For this reason I have actually written a small gem for doing this automatically together with SimpleForm. If you want to take a look, then you can find it here:

https://github.com/kaspernj/simple_form_ransack

Comment: Thanks, i have tried your gem. Hmm.. so should i modify the simple_search_for as this?  <%= search_form_for @ransack, url: browse_articles_path, method: :get do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :categories_name_cont %>
          <%= f.submit category.name, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <% end %>

Comment: I have copied and pasted your above code, but this doesn't seem to work and gives this error: "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: The instructions for the gem should be pretty straight forward if you follow the README instructions. I don't have enough information to know what goes wrong just by an error message. Sorry